# Ubuntu 20.04 theme with higher contrast title bar for active vs background window

Tags: 20.04, themes, gtk, cinnamon

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) with Cinnamon desktop.

The problem I've got is that it's hard to tell which window is active and which is in the background.

I'm running Adwaita theme for Controls and BlueMenta for Window borders, but all the Window borders themes only have very slight changes in the title bar text from dark grey to slightly lighter grey for active vs background windows.

I'd like for the whole titlebar to change colour for active vs background windows.

I believe that might be problematic with Gnome applications that now like to stuff a whole dialog worth of controls into the title bar for some reason, but I don't habitually use any Gnome apps, so I don't mind if they look even worse.

I tried creating my own theme by cloning an existing theme into a new directory and editing it, but didn't get too far - all the colours I modified in the CSS didn't have any effect on active vs background title bar colour.

(To be clear: the applications whose title bars I care about are urxvt, Firefox, Chrome, IntelliJ, Slack, etc. None of these behave or look like Gnome apps like `gnome-calculator` or `gedit`.)